# How to protect a private message from Replay attack?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, private-key

What if I send a message with a private key
My message is  "Today is party at 7"

Devil copied my encrypted text with signature

After some days the devil sent the message to the same guy I sent.

The message is not changed,my friend still got the same message of party at 7 and it is digitally signed by my private key.

What should I do to prevent this type of scenario?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent this?

Comment: I want to prevent that my message should not be sent again..

Its an obvious thing that next day my partner will be waiting for me at 7 
whereas I did not send him a message..

Comment: You should ask your partner to send you a confirmation. Though confirmation can still be intercepted. Or you could include the date in your message, or a secret word good-for-one-time.

Comment: Add a sequence number, require each message has an increasing value. Ten the receiver will know the message is a duplicate. When you stay: "What if I send a message with a private key" you mean signed with your private key, right?

Comment: yeah,, i m using private keyto encrypt.

Comment: @BilalRehman What's the issue that you see? What do you think the attacker gains by sending the message again? There are easy ways to defeat replay attacks such as message counters or time stamps. The receiver would then be required to check them.

Comment: I want to prevent replay attacks...
If you have any implemented method ..
Can u please share...

Comment: @BilalRehman What do you mean by *"implemented method"*? Your question doesn't reference any programming languages or frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replay attacks are most commonly prevented by adding an extra piece of unique information that is not part of the message. Here is a common solution:

- Add to the message a timestamp and a random value.
- If the message is older than some age (a minute, an hour, a day, depending on how messages are delivered), it generates a "message too old" error
- If the message is within that time frame, make sure you have never seen that random value before. If you have, then it is a repeat and can be simply ignored.

By adding a timestamp, you bound how long you have to keep track of "what you've seen before."

Another general approach is to make all messages idempotent. This means that applying the same message multiple times is not problematic. Systems like git have this quality. Building idempotent systems is somewhat tricky, and not easily achieved for all problems, but is a powerful solution when possible. An example of making something idempotent is to say "at this point in time, X had value Y." You can apply that message repeatedly without causing any problems (either because it updates the same record in exactly the same way, or because you ignore all points in time older than the latest value you have).

Addressing the replay attack problem happens to also solve several other problems, which is nice. Messaging systems face a fundamental problem that no message can be guaranteed to be delivered exactly once. You can guarantee at most once, or at least once, but never exactly once. (Study the [Two Generals' Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals'_Problem) for a common way of thinking through this. It is arguable that you can't actually promise "at least once" because the systems may never be connected, but we typically ignore that corner case). Idempotent systems are very nice because they are highly tolerant of "at least once" solutions.